# Alternative way of writing complex ETLs in Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We have a Synapse Analytics workspace where we have a number of simple [data flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/concepts-data-flow-overview) and [pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-pipelines) which perform simple transformations (ETLs, ELTs). Usually, they read from a data lake (ADLS Gen2) and then write back to it.

But recently, because of the much more complex business requirements, it looks like we've started writing complex transformation code inside Notebooks which I am not sure is the right thing. Mainly due to the following reasons:

- It is hard to achieve code reusability
- It is not possible to debug a bit more complex code
- Hard to apply code styling conventions (such as linters)
- Code changes get lost if you forget to 'commit' your changes
- Pretty hard to have a unit tested code

As a work around we've been building python packages and importing them in the workspace, so a few lines of code get executed by a given Notebook responsible for the invocation of the actual transformation logic. But, still, not sure if this is the way to go here. One thing I know for sure is that the Notebooks are not good for complex code transformations, version control, code reviewing etc.

I am curious to see what is the community opinion here. What do you do in a situation where your "out of the box" activities don't do the work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We've implemented some complex Spark Notebooks (mostly using Spark SQL, and a little PySpark), as well as SQL serverless notebooks. All in a Synapse Serverless environment.

I agree with your points - to expand the 'debugging' issues on the Spark side:

- Only 5000 rows can be returned, from within a notebook query
- Queries are executed 'lazily', which makes tracking down issues much
  more difficult.  Let me know if you haven't run into this yet, and I'll explain

As far as I can tell - there is no great workaround. This is just what Synapse *is*.   I'm not sure it's a great solution, especially for a Data Warehouse.  It might be better for big data processing + ad hoc analysis.